# How to include a css class that is an image on codeigniter form submit?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, form-submit

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'class' => "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
        'name' => 'report'
    );

    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> ';
    echo form_submit($data, 'Report');

    $data = array(
        'class'=>"btn btn-primary btn-lg",
        'name' => "search"
    );

    echo anchor("",'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search',$data);

    echo form_close();
?>
```

I want to include `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>` on the form_submit. This span class is an image, I cant find a way to put it inside the button.
http://puu.sh/6UbE8.jpg

The second one "echo anchor", its second parameter has a span class which is also an image followed by a word "Search". This is exactly what I want the previous "form_submit" to be looks like. http://puu.sh/6UbFt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form_button instead of form_submit, and wrap your span around label.

```
$data = array(
        'class' => "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
        'name' => 'report'
        );
echo form_button($data, '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign">Report</span>');
```

hope it will help

Comment: if I change it into form_button. How would I get data from the same page. Because I had a code like this in controller, for form_submit
if (!empty($this->input->post("report")))
  {
       echo $this->input->post('plateNum');
  }

Comment: use javascript onclick to submit your form ie add `"onclick"=>"this.form.submit()"` to $data array. so it will react same as submit button.

Comment: after I try that the  `if ($this->input->post("report"))`
dont work on controller, this line is for me to check which button in view is clicked. pls help~

Comment: You can use Javascript and hidden fields to achieve that. onclick of button first populate hidden field and then submit the form. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'report',
    'id' => 'report',
    'value' => 'true',
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
);

echo form_button($data);
```

you can check `http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html`

Comment: if I use form_button, my form_open stated above wont work anymore.

Comment: use javascript onclick to submit your form